# ElementUI: How to use <el-table> to traverse data which in a database

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

Here is my code:

```
<template>
<div>
  <el-table
    ref="multipleTable"
    :data="users">

    <el-table-column
      prop="id"
      label="id">
    </el-table-column>

    <el-table-column
      prop="name"
      label="name">
    </el-table-column>

  </el-table>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name:'User',
    data() {
        return{
            users:[],
        }
    },
    
}
</script>
```

My database have 'user' table and have id and name. I know use `v-for="user in users"` to traverse data in <table>, but I don't know how to do it in <el-table>

Comment: You dont need to loop over rows, it does it itself

Answer (score 0):

`el-table` is a component itself and will traverse the data you pass internally.
You have to pass an array of objects to it, so it will iterate it automatically.

Please refer to the docs for examples [here](https://element.eleme.io/2.10/#/en-US/component/table#basic-table)

Answer (score 0):

You need to this like this for example:

```
    <template>
<div>
  <el-table
    :data="users"
    style="width: 100%">

    <el-table-column
      prop="id"
      label="ID"
      width="180">
    </el-table-column>

    <el-table-column
      prop="name"
      label="Name"
      width="180">
    </el-table-column>

  </el-table>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return{
            users: [
                {
                    id: 0,
                    name: 'Name 1'
                },
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: 'Name 2'
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    name: 'Name 3'
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    name: 'Name 4'
                },
            ],
        }
    },
    
}
</script>
```